# How Insert Array String From One Input Html Form And Fetch Another Data From Them

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have one input HTML form that I insert the values like below to it:

```
<input name="name" type="text" value="data1,data2,data3,...">
```

Then even data which insert to form has an ID in another table;

For example id of data1 is 1, id of data2 is 2,...

Now I take the value of them form like:

```
$_POST['name']
```

So that I input data with ',' and then I can't use:

```
implode (',',$_POST['name'])
```

1. How can I fetch id from database for each data which input like top and store them in one variable like $name?
2. How can I insert the id's which is fetch from data1,data2,...to MySQL database as array Like id1,id2,...

Comment: Do you want to fetch all the rows from a table and then put the ID's in one single variable? Why do you want to do that, what would you like to achieve with putting all the id's in one single variable?

Comment: no just every id which has related to data and store them as array of id's in on variable to insert this variable to another table

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE id IN(".implode (',',$_POST['name']).")";
$data = mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die("Error fetching data")
$name = "";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
    $name .= $row['id'].",";
}
```

you have to be more clear about your second question